# Logic, "and" operator between a set of formulas and a formula

Tags: logic, sets, propositional-logic

Consider a set $S$ of formulas $\beta_i$ and a formula $\alpha$, if we have a condition such as **$S \land \alpha$ is inconsistent** what we have to calculate to check the inconsistency of $S \land \alpha$? In other words, what is the result of $S \land \alpha$?

For example, $S=\{\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3\}$

Comment: If you already know that the formula is inconsistent then why do you need to check it?

Comment: @fade2black i don't know if the formula is inconsistent, it is a condition, something like $if( (S\land \alpha) is consistent) then ...$ so i have to check the inconsistency of the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set $S$ of formulas (propositional logic) is **consistent** if there is a truth assignment under which all formulas in $S$ are *true*, in other words if there is a *model* of $S$. Alternatively, $\{\beta_1, \beta_2, ...,  \beta_n \}$ is consistent, iff $\beta_1 \wedge \beta_2 \wedge ... \wedge \beta_n$ is satisfiable.

You could just find a truth assignment such that $\alpha \wedge \beta_1 \wedge \beta_2 \wedge \beta_3$ is true. If the number of variables is small then you can check it by hand by creating a truth-table, or use [Method of analytic tableaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux). Also, note that the Satisfiability problem (SAT) is NP complete.

You can also use a [resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)) procedure to show that a formula is unsatisfiable (inconsistent).

Comment: So having one **beta** of **S** inconsistent with **alpha** make **S and alpha** inconsistent regardless of other **beta**s

Comment: Right. In addition, when we say that $S=\{\beta_1,...,\beta_n\}$ is consistent we mean that $\beta_1 \wedge... \wedge\beta_n$ is satisfiable. But if $\alpha$ is not consistent with $S$ it does not yet mean that $\alpha$ is inconsistent with a subset of $S$.

Comment: How is that!, if $\alpha$ is not consistent with $S$ then forcly $\alpha$ is inconsistent with a subset of $S$ except when $\alpha$ is inconsistent

Comment: $\alpha$ is consistent with $S$ means $\alpha \wedge \beta_1 \wedge \beta_2 \wedge \beta_3$ is satisfiable. So if $\alpha$ is inconsistent, say, with $\beta_2$ then $\alpha \wedge \beta_2$ is  not satisfiable (always false), and hence $\alpha \wedge \beta_1 \wedge \beta_2 \wedge \beta_3$ is false too (independent of $\beta_1$ and $\beta_3$). So having one $\beta$ inconsistent with $\alpha$ makes $\alpha$ inconsistent with $S$. However, $S' = \{\beta_1, \beta_3\}$ may be consistent with $\alpha$ as long as $\alpha \wedge \beta_1 \wedge \beta_3$ is satisfiable.

Comment: I'm okay with your last comment, but please review your first one, you said "... But if  $\alpha$ is not consistent with  $S$ it does not yet mean that $\alpha$ is inconsistent with a subset of $S$"

Comment: I think it is not wrong. "...if $\alpha$ is not consistent with $S$ "  (as in the previous example $\alpha$ and $\beta_2$) . "it does not mean that $\alpha$ is inconsistent with a subset of $S$ " (as in the previous example $S' = \{\beta_1, \beta_3\}$)

Comment: I still confused about it, what i find contradictory with your first comment is that (if $\alpha$ is inconsistent with $S$ then there exist a subset of $S$ that is inconsistent with $\alpha$) for example as in the previous example $\alpha$ is inconsistent with every subset of $S$ that contains $\beta_2$

Comment: I don't claim that if $\alpha$ is inconsistent with $S$ then there is a subset $S'$ which must be consistent with $\alpha$. I mean that *there may be* a subset $S'$ consistent with $\alpha$.

Comment: Okay, i'm okay, from you first comment I've understood that you said (if $\alpha$ is inconsistent with $S$ then there no subset $S'$ of $S$ which is inconsistent with $\alpha$) which is not what you wanted to say. Thank you for your help.